# What does scrap banking mean?

Tags: team-fortress-2, terminology, steam

I hear it all the time. They're looking for scrap? Crafting scrap? Trading scrap?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Scrap banking is the process of trading scrap metal for common, low-value weapons.  Typically this is at the rate of two weapons per one scrap.

If someone needs a scrap banker, they are looking for scrap and have weapons.  If someone is scrap banking, they have scrap for trade.

This is effective for the person with weapons because it means not having to go craft scrap with weapons (if they even have the correct slots to be able to craft scrap), and effective for the person with scrap because often some weapons they are given will be worth more than half a scrap.

Comment: You can have it straight from the source. I am a scrap banker in TF2 and it is very easy and fun to do! It is good for new and old TF2 players. Each day, I go onto trading servers in TF2 and find at least 7 people that want to have scrap for weapons! I charge two weapons for one scrap. It brings in a lot of common and sometimes uncommon weapons on the table. In one day I found every weapon I ever wanted in TF2. As for what "Ian Pugsley" said, It is all correct.